# Three.js ShaderMaterial artifacts

Tags: three.js, shader

I tried a very simple test using Three.js ShaderMaterial.
I load a 2048x2048 jpg image as a texture for my height map and apply it to deform a PlaneBufferGeometry in the vertex shader.
I also apply the same texture for the diffuse color in the fragment shader.
Globally it works but I see some big artifacts as shown in this [screenshot](https://tylart.pagesperso-orange.fr/ShaderTest/artifacts2.jpg)

The artifact always appears along a line parallel to the X axis and passing through the camera.
I have the problem on all three.js version I tried (r105, r114)

The code is yet very simple, anyone know what am I doing wrong ?

Javascript

```
        var textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
        var testTextureBump = textureLoader.load( './front_b.jpg' );
        var testGeometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(3000, 3000, 500, 500);
        var testUniforms = {
          uTextureBump: { value: testTextureBump }
        };
        var testMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
          uniforms:       testUniforms,
          vertexShader: document.getElementById( 'vertexShader' ).textContent,
          fragmentShader: document.getElementById( 'fragmentShader' ).textContent,
          side: THREE.FrontSide,
          blending: THREE.NormalBlending,
          depthWrite: false,
          wireframe: false,
          transparent: true
        });
        var testMesh = new THREE.Mesh( testGeometry, testMaterial );
        scene.add( testMesh );
```

Vertex shader

```
      uniform sampler2D uTextureBump;

      varying vec2 vUv;

      void main() {
        vUv = uv;
        vec4 diffuseTexture = texture2D(uTextureBump, uv);
        vec3 positionHeight = position.xyz;
        positionHeight.z += diffuseTexture.r * 20.0;
        gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(positionHeight, 1.0);
      }
```

Fragment shader

```
      precision highp float;
      precision highp int;

      uniform sampler2D uTextureBump;

      varying vec2 vUv;

      void main (void) {
        vec4 texture = texture2D(uTextureBump, vUv);
        gl_FragColor = vec4( texture.rgb, 1.0 );
      }
```

You can see the problem in this [demo](https://tylart.pagesperso-orange.fr/ShaderTest/index.html)

Move your mouse on the left or right and you'll see the artifacts.
You can fly around as I use the standard THREE.FlyControl service.

The corresponding project file can be download [here](https://tylart.pagesperso-orange.fr/ShaderTest/shader_test.zip)

Comment: Remove or comment out `depthWrite: false,` in the material. And what reason to have `transparent: true`?

Comment: Thank you, it was the depthWrite attribute, I thought I had already tested without it but obviously not.

Comment: Actually a second parameter produces the same effect, independantly from depthWrite : the "near" parameter of the THREE.PerspectiveCamera.
It mustn't be greater than about 0.01, otherwise the artifact reappers.